# Does the USB-C Digital AV Multiport Adapter transmit 4K 60Hz signal from M1 MBP?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, usb, 4k, apple-silicon

I have a 13" 2020 M1 MacBook Pro (MBP).

I'm currently experiencing some issues with a third-party USB-C hub. I'm considering replacing it with a [USB-C Digital AV Multiport Adapter](https://www.apple.com/au/shop/product/MUF82ZA/A/usb-c-digital-av-multiport-adapter?fnode=32eda35bf81d994f5a3f5f1b9f4272e42c54e654f9f8e8160cd2deaad4b5f14e9cba378c0bddb4881fbce6c0f65d02dc1e156813d0d7760266aa34921466bc5c2693573693720d21743f11c68805ef2a604690b1e1b0a39b9f276b2765a78f43). The page for the adapter, if read literally, suggests that the M1 MacBook Air (MBA) can drive 4K 60Hz video via this adapter, but the M1 MBP cannot.

Can anyone confirm that this adapter can transmit 4K 60Hz signal from an M1 MBP?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it can, but you may have the old version of the Apple Digital AV adaptor. You need to make sure the adapter version is A2XXX, not A1XXX, since Apple updated that adapter in 2019 to support HDMI 2.0.

I have an M1 MacBook Pro and I can confirm the updated version of the Apple Digital AV adaptor does support a 4K 60hz HDMI connection.

Answer (score 2):

I just tried plugging a 4K monitor into my M1 MBP using that adapter, and it only gave me options up to 30Hz at 4K.

I also didn't see any M1 Macs listed in the 60Hz list. So I suspect that all the M1 Macs will only run at 30Hz using a 4K screen on that adapter.

Comment: https://www.apple.com/de/macbook-air/specs/ and https://www.apple.com/de/macbook-pro-13/specs/. This clearly states that the new M1 powered MBA and MBP can support a 6K 60Hz screen. This implies 4K 60Hz is supported too.

Comment: Not through that adapter, it doesn’t

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to downvote, now I can't undo that unless you edit your answer. However, this seems ridiculous, yet you have the hardware... Really did not expect that.

Comment: My daily driver is an M1 MBP. I’m currently using a Caldigit TB3+ docking station and a DisplayLink dock to drive two 4K screens, because even the MacBook PRO only supports one external screen directly. And boy-oh-boy is DisplayLink a “workaround” and not a fix. I edited the answer to fix a simple typo

Comment: Excellent analysis in this answer. +1 indeed and DisplayLink has a lot of issues for someone that cares about 10 Hz let alone 30 Hz differences.

Comment: Just for completeness sake: You must ensure that you're using a correct type of HDMI cable with the adapter. I have tried before that the wrong type of HDMI cable limits you to 30 Hz at 4k, where just changing the HDMI cable gives the new option of 60 Hz using this adapter. However, I have not tested it on the M1 MBP - I have only an Apple Silicon Mac Mini to test with here.

Comment: Thanks for editing. +1 also from me, really really stupid that this doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks all. 
I know the M1 MBP can support up to 6K at 60Hz. I am currently using an external display at 4K 60Hz from the M1 MBP, using a third-party USB-C hub. My question is not whether the computer supports 4K 60Hz; it does. My question is about the compatibility of the adapter. 

I don't think it's right to say that there are no M1 Macs listed in the 60Hz [=list for the adapter. The list includes "MacBook Air (2020)". But the M1 MBP is not listed (the only 13" is the 2020 four thunderbolt ports Intel machine).

Comment: Bu thanks for trying @ScottEarle, I'll avoid buying the adapter

Comment: MacBook Air (2020) refers to the early-2020 Intel MacBook Air, I believe

Answer (score 1):

I can also confirm that 4k@60Hz is supported on a MacBook Pro (13-inch, M1, 2020, two thunderbolt ports) running macOS 12.0.1 (21A559), with the USB-C Digital AV Multiport Adapter A2119.

This is despite what the linked page says.